# Do collections that prevent inserting the duplicate elements work slower?

Tags: .net, collections, set, duplicates

Do collections that prevent inserting the duplicate elements work slower(than the non-checking ones), as I guess they implement some kind of check on each element within against duplication?

Or it is not correct or tolerable in most of the cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of course, but most sets are likely to be optimised in some form to check for containment quickly. For example, `HashSet<T>` is basically a hash table of values - so it's just a hash lookup.

I don't know of any collections which would check *every* existing element for equality (unless you have a horrible hash collision situation etc).

Comment: I think pencilCake means `MyList.Contains(myObject)`. A List wouldn't do this by itself, but manually called it would compare each item with each other.

Comment: Jon, this is a citation from the book Manning NHibernate in Action : "An ISet collection (in the library Iesi.Collections), for example, calls Equals() on each object you put in the ISet, to determine (and prevent) duplicate elements."  I am not sure if it is true or not, though as you talk about optimization.

Comment: @pencilCake: As I say, it depends on the implementation. You're referring to one very specific implementation, which sounds like it's not a terribly sensible one for a normal set.

Comment: @Tim: The question specifically talks about "collections that prevent inserting the duplicate elements" which wouldn't include `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

That totally depends on the implementation of the collection you are using - if it is based on a List<T> there will be a performance penalty.

However, if a HashSet<T> is used, the performance will be almost the same.

Still, performance shouldn't be the motivation here. If you want to allow duplicate items, use a list that does, otherwise use one that doesn't.